# JQuery navigation warnings to be conditional on input types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a script, which warns users when they try to navigate away from a page before saving any changes.

However I want it to ignore this for certain classes when redirected to other pages from a select dropdown menu if no changes have been made BUT if changes to other input fields have been made and they try to navigate away via this select dropdown then the warning should appear. This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var unsaved = false;

    $(":input").change(function(){
        unsaved = true;
    });

    $('.send').click(function() {
       unsaved = false;
    });

    function unloadPage(){ 
        if(unsaved){
            return "You have unsaved changes on this page. Do you want to leave this page and discard your changes or stay on this page?";
        }
    }

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
       if(unsaved){
           return "You have unsaved changes on this page. Do you want to leave this page and discard your changes or stay on this page?";
       }
    });

   //Monitor dynamic inputs
   $(document).on('change', ':input', function(){
       unsaved = true;
   });

   $(document).on('change', '.send1', function(){ 
       unsaved = false;
   });

  window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;
});
```

This is some of the html:

```
<select class="form-control send1" name="menus" onchange="location =   this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"> 
    <option value="/pf" selected>Preferences</option>
    <option value="/pers">Personal</option>
/select>    

<input type="email" class="form-control" id="newsletter" name="newsletter" placeholder="Enter email" value="">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="adminfirstname" value="" placeholder="First name">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sample btn-md reset send" id="send" name="commit"><b>Save</b></button>
```

So how can the warning appear if they use the select dropdown to navigate and have filled in the input fields and similarly no warning to appear if no input fields have been filled in?

I tried something like this, but I don't think it picks up if `:input` is not `class = send1`:

```
 $(document).on('change', '.send1', function(){ 
  if($(":input").not('.send1')){
    $(":input").change(function(){
      unsaved = true;
     });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply remove `unsaved = false` from your select onchange.

Comment: Hi.....removing `unsaved = false` from  `$(document).on('change', '.send1', function(){ 
       unsaved = false;});`, doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @user94628 Oh you're right, select is changed from `$(":input")`, try this selector instead: `$(":input:not(select)")`  (and no select onchange)

Comment: Thanks.....if you see the script in my question...then there I'm trying to say when the select is changed and the input is not `.send1` then other input changes should set 'unsaved = true'. I'm not sure if there's an error in the script as it doesn't work.